# Azure DevOps server to Azure DevOps Service migration

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I have migrated an On Premise Azure DevOps 2020 server to an Azure DevOps Services as a dry run.

The migration mapped my existing andy@g.......-g.....co.uk account to my andy@.....onmicrosoft.com account setup in Azure Active directory.

Which account do I use to login to the Azure DevOps Services project. I can use the one I used to do the migration but neither of the other accounts appear to be working, what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has this issue, I have worked out that I need to use the andy@.....onmicrosoft.com account setup in Azure Active directory to logon.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

How migration works:
It looks for the identity in the Azure DevOps Server synced with the local active directory and if that account exists in Azure Active Directory, Identity mapping csv file during pre-migration validation can show the details, or you can visit the document for more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/migrate/migration-import?view=azure-devops#generate-import-files). it syncs it with Azure DevOps Services post migration. You need to visit portal.azure.com "Azure Active Directory" by default it has the mapped identify if not you can add one as onmicrosoft.com as a guest identity or outlook.com as a guest, you can add as many identities there and it will take care of it. In order to add users or guest users from AAD follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/remove-users-prohibit-access?view=azure-devops).